# Induced EMF Graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-induction

**edit**: EMF changes due to one of the factors, not stated, so it is not relevant to the question

**{this is a past paper question regarding how the induced EMF varies in a moving conductor within a magnetic field.}**

I think of the rate of change of the EMF induced in a moving coil in a magnetic field, as the derivative of the the rate of change of the magnetic field density. I know the an EMF is induced in a conductor when it leaves and or enters a magnetic field.

So, hence I am either choosing between C or D. However, I don't know the theory of which one is correct, nor the significance of its y intercept at y = 0 varying between the graphs. Can someone please explain the theory and correct me if my thinking is wrong.

The answer is **C:**

I have attached the image below
[image: image of the picture]

Comment: Are you sure that the conductor is moving? I'd have thought that the question was about a stationary coil through which there is a uniform magnetic field of flux density varying with time.

Comment: You may be right, I based that the assumption it was an current carrying conductor due to the fact that a change in EMF has been induced. 

It is moving perpendicular to the field with a velocity v, no rotations, in the a fixed axis. Is what I presumed

Comment: But an emf would also be induced in a stationary coil through which the magnetic flux is changing because the flux density is changing.

Comment: That is true. I just said that presumption because it is one of the factors, but it holds no relevance to the question, and it should just be that an EMF is induced on a current carrying coil in a magnetic field